# vim-latex and Okular: forward/inverse search not working for DVI

Tags: linux, forward-inverse-search, vim, vim-latex, okular

I'm trying to get **DVI** forward search to work (I don't think SyncTeX is relevant) with `vim-latex`/`latex-suite` and Okular. I'm using Arch Linux.

I've been following the official `vim-latex` beginner's guide, and am up to [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-quick-forward-searching.html) step. Some info:

- The `\ll` command correctly compiles the code. I can view the resulting DVI file in Okular.
- The `\lv` command correctly opens Okular and displays the file.
- If Okular is already open, the `\ll` command also causes Okular to reload the file automatically. I'm not sure if this is some sign that forward search is almost working, or if, by default, Okular just reloads when it detects changes.
- I installed `vim-latex` with Vundle, so I have the directory `~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/ftplugin/` instead of `~/.vim/ftplugin/`. There is no `tex.vim` file in `ftplugin/`, but there is `bib_latexSuite.vim`, `latex-suite/`, and `tex_latexSuite.vim`.
- Okular is shown [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/forward-searching.html) to support forward search.

---

As for inverse search, I placed the command `gvim -c ":RemoteOpen +%l %f"` (according to [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/inverse-searching.html) page) in Okular > Settings > Configure Okular > Editor > Command, but Shift+leftclick in browse mode doesn't do anything.